# How to work aroud 100 http callouts from future method?

Tags: trigger

How to work aroud 100 http callouts from future method ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use chain `queueable` instead.
Chain `queueable` class to keep on calling itself by changing the input params.

Something like this.

```
public class CallOutQueuable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

    public CallOutQueuable(List<Account> accounts) {
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        List<Account> firstChunk = new List<Account>();
        List<Account> restChunk = new List<Account>();
        if (this.accounts.size() > 100) {
            for (Integer i = 0; i < this.accounts.size(); i++) {
                if (i < 100) {
                    firstChunk.add(this.accounts[i]);
                } else {
                    restChunk.add(this.accounts[i]);
                }
            }
        } else {
            firstChunk.addAll(this.accounts);
        }


        // Do 100 Callouts with `firstChunk`
        // Then recall the same queueable class again with the rest of the chunk from the list if the list was more than 100 size.


        if (!restChunk.isEmpty()) {
            System.enqueueJob(new CallOutQueuable(restChunk));
        }
    }
}
```